# Use smartnsf within xpages

Tags: java, xpages

I like the idea to setup micro-services for my Notes database via the smartnsf extension/plugin. I would like to use these micro-services then further within my xpages application. I am just wondering how I could use them best?

Is it by setting up an HttpURLConnection in my java class and direct to an smartnsf url or some other approach?

Comment: If you have come up with a more complete answer to your own question, feel free to post it back (and accept it if you feel it's a full answer). I'd love to hear what you came up with. Personally, I'm partial to Oliver's answer, since one of the goals of SmartNSF is to incorporate business logic into the endpoints, giving us something substantive beyond say Domino Data Services. Feel free to consume the endpoints wherever makes sense in your application though!

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to use a client based script to access the REST service which SmartNSF provides such as Angular or React to generate a UI.

Comment: why does it say then: SmartNSF also brings great value to XPages, Java and SSJS Gurus?

Comment: @PatrickKwinten: Because you can create the whole UI with XPages Dojo Components, if you like the pain

Comment: what has dojo to do with java?

Comment: Dojo is the JS Framework shipped with XPages. Java has a lot of Webframeworks, like Spring.

Comment: IMHO Malin's question basically answers one good use case for why XPages / Java / SSJS - reusing the same functionality from within and outside the application. Beyond that, the OpenNTF Slack channel is the best place for a discussion about other use cases rather than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents: go for URLConnection. You can find a good sample code here:
https://edm00se.io/xpages/server-rest-with-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

In general accessing it via standard http/s connection is the right way.